# Gas settings when sending a tx

Tags: gas, gas-price, pending-transactions, nonce, goerli

I currently have several txs stuck on Pending even after passing them 100 gwei of gasPrice while current baseFee is 0.000001086 gwei (on Goerli and using ethers.js).

```js
const ops = {
    gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from('30000000'),
    gasPrice: ethers.BigNumber.from('100134698068') 
};
```

I've been re-sending them with the nonce of the stuck tx with even higher and higher gasPrice, but they don't get included.

What settings can I add so they get validated asap?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have enough ether to pay for the transaction fee? If gasLimit * gasPrice + value is greater than the available balance the transaction will get stuck until they are replaced, or there is enough balance for the fees. Can you share the pending transaction hashes?

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I was using a greater nonce than the stuck tx (by 1). As soon as I figured that out and sent it with the correct nonce, it went through

Comment: Please, add that as answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I was using a greater nonce than the stuck tx (by 1).

When using `ethers.provider.getTransactionCount(addr, 'pending')` to get the nonce of the last stuck tx, be sure to use the result from that call and not one nonce higher (my error).

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the Gas Price from the Blockchain instead of hardCoding it .

```
const gasPrice = ethers.utils.formatUnits(await provider.getGasPrice(), 'gwei')
const options = {gasLimit: 3000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits(gasPrice, 'gwei')}
```

Comment: That's not working. I hard-coded it to 1000x its value because fetching it directly wasn't working.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: No error. The txs just get stuck indefinitely, even after resending them with the same nonce and a higher gasPrice.

Comment: Do you mean your JS Script shows transaction Processed but it's not processed on etherscan Explorer?

Comment: JS script doesn't show anything. It's literally the definition of stuck. When it hits the line of code of signer.sendTransaction(), it doesn't pass that line to the next one. And once I quit the script and query pending txs, I see that it's been sent

Comment: I once had this problem and iv'e changed My wallet and tried freshly with another wallet. I used the above mentioned mathod (getting gasPrice from chain). so try another wallet send some eth to it and then use the method.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that. Thanks :)